# MVC3 Save Model multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I need to be able to save the same model multiple times in with a for loop.  My Action has two parameters, InventoryViewModel movie and int quantity.  If the quantity is 3, for example, I need to save three copies to the database.

In my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addInventory(InventoryViewModel movie, int Quantity)
    {
        movie.Inventory.isAvail = true;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Quantity; i++)
            {
                inventoryRepository.save(movie.Inventory);
                movie = new InventoryViewModel();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
        return View("index", movie);
    }
```

I thought setting the movie = new InventoryViewModel would create a new instance of the movie, but it doesn't work.  If I take that line out, it hits the else statement after it adds the first copy to the database.  The CheckoutNum is the primary key of the table so I cannot set it to 0 in the for loop.  I can't remember the exact error, but it's something about the primary key cannot be modified.

Repository:

```
public void save(Inventory movie)
    {
        if (movie.CheckoutNum == 0)
            db.Inventory.Add(movie);
        else
            db.Entry<Inventory>(movie).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first saved your entity it is already flagged as "not new". So on succeeding calls it will do an update. What you should do is create a new instance of `Inventory` on each loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Quantity; i++)
{
    var entityToSave = new Inventory();
    // map the property values to save

    inventoryRepository.save(entityToSave);
}
```

Comment: That wipes out the movieId when I do that.

Comment: You can ignore that previous comment, I see what you meant now.  I missed the comment you had.  Thanks!